# how to reset countdowntimer each time on starting it with new values?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am making an app which uses `CountDownTimer` and shows each second 
value in a text view. I have 3 buttons with different times but 
on pressing the different buttons, the value on textview shows the    `CountDownTimer`
value of all the times simultaneously how to reset countdowntimer 
each time before calling it.

```
    package com.rebootapp.myapplication;

    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

    }

    public void runtimer(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.min3:
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timer(10000);
                break;
            case R.id.min5:
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timer(20000);
                break;
            case R.id.min10:
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timer(30000);
                break;
            default:
                textView.setText("");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void timer(int t){
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            }.start();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Why is the `countDownTimer.cancel()` is commented out? you do need to cancel the previous counter before starting the new.

Answer (score 0):

i used this and the issue got resolved inside the timer() function and removed 
countdowntimer.cancel(); from all cases and it got resolved

```
 if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
```